# shiny R reactive function is not working

Tags: r, shiny

I've started using the Shiny package and I'm having problems with the reactive function.
link to csv file - [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Ur4epvA6w-ZmRRaDItVjRnSTg/view?usp=sharing) 
The reactive function is not working in the following code:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(jpeg)
  library(grid)
  library(DT)

  ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage
        (

        titlePanel("Rapid Interpretation of Eye Movements"),
        tags$style("body {background-color: #ffffcc;}"),
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
        tags$hr(),
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 10, class = "well",
                 h4("Left plot controls right plot"),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(width = 10,plotOutput("plot", height = 500, brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)))
                 )))
        ))

  server<- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

    filedata <- reactive({
      infile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(infile)) {
        # User has not uploaded a file yet
        return(NULL)
      }
      read.csv(infile$datapath)
    })

    output$plot <-renderPlot({

      bg <- rasterGrob(readJPEG(
        paste0("C:/Users/tyaacov/Downloads/shinyProject/pics/1.jpg")), interpolate=TRUE)

      fixationdata <- filedata()

      df <- data.frame(fixationdata$HorzPos, 
                       fixationdata$VertPos,
                       d = densCols(fixationdata$HorzPos,
                                    fixationdata$VertPos,
                                    colramp = colorRampPalette(rev(rainbow(10, end = 4/6)))))



      ggplot(df) + annotation_custom(bg, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) + 
        geom_point(aes(fixationdata$HorzPos, 
                       fixationdata$VertPos, col = d), size = 1) +
        scale_color_identity() +  theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(name="",limits = c(0, 920)) + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) + scale_y_continuous(name="",limits = c(0, 255))
    })

  })

  shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

I'm receiving errors about `fixationdata` not being found. From checking things separately I can only guess the source to this problem is the reactive function.
Does anyone know where was I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is there a UI file that's supposed to go with this so that I can try running it?

Comment: yeah.. added the UI code to the question.. Thaks..

Comment: Great, that helps, thanks. Do you also get the error about `,    width = '8%'` being an invalid option? Are there any other packages you have loaded? I think you loaded `raster`, `jpeg` and `grid` is that right?  Can you attach the file `C:/Users/tyaacov/Downloads/shinyProject/pics/1.jpg`?

Comment: Also, whatever csv file is needed. Sorry to request so much, we just have to be able to replicate your situation so that we can fix the error.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yeah you're right.. I minimized the code so the width error is not an issue.. added a link to the csv file as well.. packages are in the top of the code.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(DT)

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage
            (

            titlePanel("Rapid Interpretation of Eye Movements"),
            tags$style("body {background-color: #ffffcc;}"),
            fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                               '.csv')),
            tags$hr(),
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 10, class = "well",
                     h4("Left plot controls right plot"),
                     fluidRow(
                       column(width = 10,plotOutput("plot", height = 500, brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)))
                     )))
            ))

server<- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })


  output$plot <-renderPlot({

    if (is.null(input$file1)) return()
    #if (input$action==0) return()
    #isolate({

    library(ggplot2)

    fixationdata <- filedata()

    df <- data.frame(fixationdata$HorzPos, 
                     fixationdata$VertPos,
                     d = densCols(fixationdata$HorzPos,
                                  fixationdata$VertPos,
                                  colramp = colorRampPalette(rev(rainbow(10, end = 4/6)))))
    ggplot(df)  + 
      geom_point(aes(fixationdata$HorzPos, 
                     fixationdata$VertPos, col = d), size = 1) +
      scale_color_identity() +  theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(name="",limits = c(0, 920)) + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) + scale_y_continuous(name="",limits = c(0, 255))
  #})

  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's still shows the error- Error in eval: object 'fixationdata' not found

Comment: I did not see this error, have you tried update R and the libraries?